# Is there any way to add JsonSerializerSettings to a custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net

In using json.net I'm required to adjust the (de)serializer settings, so I create a `JsonSerializerSettings` instance and use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(someString, mySerializerSettings.ss);
```

But I then find it necessary to use a custom `JsonConverter` for some banged up data, and then use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(someString, new myConverter());
```

But I'm now finding I need to use both `JsonSerializerSettings` and a custom converter but I don't see any overloads of the `DeserializeObject` method that would allow that.

What might I be missing?

I'm using .net v4.5.2 and json.net v10.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) has a `Converters` collection.  So add your converter to that collection and then pass the settings to `DeserializeObject`.

```
mySerializerSettings.ss.Converters.Add(new myConverter());
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(someString, mySerializerSettings.ss);
```

Comment: thanks , this was staring me right in the face as i was already adding a StringEnumConverter to the Converters collection. I didn't make the obvious connection.