# How do I handle erroneously-detected reference loops with JsonConvert.SerializeObject() when JsonCoverters need to be passed?

Tags: c#, json.net

We have a need to serialize objects with versioning, so we are encapsulating them in an envelope:

```
protected void OnStateChanged(Object state) 
{
    var envelope = new WorkerStateData<Object> 
    {
        StateVersion = workerConfig.CurrentStateVersion,
        Value = state
    };
    String serializedState = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope, new VersionConverter());
}
```

With one of our entities that need to be serialized, Newtonsoft is detecting a reference loop. I've confirmed that no such loop exists by forcing serialization `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize`:

```
var serializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializeSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
String serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state, Formatting.Indented, serializeSettings);
```

This test serialization succeeds with no reference loop.

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be an overload of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` which accepts both `JsonSerializerSettings` and `JsonConverter[]`. Without having both of those pieces of functionality, I can't integrate this fix into our main code base.

Can anyone suggest another way to bypass the reference loop check?

Comment: Is this just a duplicate of [Is there any way to add JsonSerializerSettings to a custom JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51429420/3744182), or do you need some help with the erroneous `ReferenceLoopHandling` error?

Comment: My dev lead wanted to avoid using custom serialization settings.  I was hoping to find out why Json.Net was detecting a reference loop. It turns out it is because we are overriding the Equals() method in one of our classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonSerializerSettings` has a property which is a list of converters:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope, Formatting.Indented, new 
        JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [github issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2627) that I submitted to the Json.Net team. The problem we experienced was due to us overriding the default `Equals()` method in one of our classes.

While there really isn't a reference loop, updating Json.Net to handle such situations might break backwards compatibility. Long story short, guidance from Json.Net is to use custom Serializer settings as proposed in the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: See [Why doesn't reference loop detection use reference equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938352/3744182).  You can use `JsonSerializerSettings.EqualityComparer` to override Json.NET's behavior.

Comment: My dev lead wanted to use only default serialization settings, so we had to deal with the problem.